# Duplicated apps installed by Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have an app `X` that has two activities `X` and `F` that appear in the drawer.
I also use `X` as a library for another app `A`, that also has two activities that appear in the drawer, `A` and `M`.

So, what I've always done in Eclipse to install them was:

1. Clean both packages
2. Install `A`.
3. Go to `Project > Properties > Android`, disabling in `Is Library`.
4. Install `X`
5. Enable again `Is Library` for `X`.

With this procedure, I always ended up with the 4 activities in the drawer.

Now, I'm trying to migrate to Android Studio. I created a project and imported both apps as modules. Now to install them:

I repeated the above procedure, but editing the first line of the `build.gradle` file of `X` instead of (3) and (5) above. Kind of a pain, but it works... **except** for a very strange problem: I end up with TWO `A` activities and TWO `F` activities in the drawer (yes, same names!), plus `M` and `X`, now I have 6 instead of 4. The two `A` activities, the `M` and one `F` belong to `A`, while `X` and `F` to `X` (as it has always been).

Even more crazy stuff: one of the `A` does not work properly, while the other does. In the app manager there is only one copy of `A` and another of `X`, as it has always been.

Why is this?? What I am doing wrong? How can `A` have installed two copies of itself??? Or maybe this is a bug of Nova launcher? (rooted stock Android 4.4 here).

Thanks!

L.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen if you have multiple activities specified as launcher activities. Please run app after making sure that only one activity is specified as launcher in manifest.

Comment: I see, I'll try it. However, I do need that each app has 2 independent  launcher activities. I tried with widgets but it didn't work as I needed with eclipse (don't remember now which was the problem). Anyway, Eclipse didn't give me this problem, so it is an Android Studio related issue. What I don't understand is why I get 2 A launcher items comming from the same app....

Comment: I tested your suggestion. I can actually have the 2 launcher activities `A` and `M` for `A` as I always had, but I have to remove all launcher activities for `X` in its manifest when compiling `A`. So I need to edit two files of module `X` back and forth.... quite inconvenient. I guess I will stay with Eclipse until Android Studio matures (it also eats most of my memory). Thanks!

Comment: Everything back to normal after I install the Eclipse version of `A`.